# Logic and calling functions. Help me understand this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have some code that is basically a demo for how `dict` works.  My problem is, I am not sure exactly when it is calling the `process_order()` function.  It seems like the main loop (`go_shopping`) never calls it, but the script seems to work.  The `go_shopping` function calls `get_item`, but that doesn't call `process_order` either.  I am also having trouble with the line `if not process_order(order, cart):`.  What does the `if not` part mean in this case?  Is that where it is calling `process_order`?  It doesn't seem like it from the print statements, other wise it should print 'if not' when you add an item to the cart dictionary object.

Am I on the right track or missing something simple?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

def get_item():
    print("[command] [item] (command is 'a' to add, 'd' to delete, 'q' to quit.)")
    line = input()

    command = line[:1]
    item = line[2:]

    return command, item

def add_to_cart(item, cart):
    if not item in cart:
        cart[item] = 0
    cart[item] += 1

def delete_from_cart(item, cart):
    if item in cart:
        if cart[item] <= 0:
            del cart[item]
        else:
            cart[item] -= 1

def process_order(order, cart):
    command, item = order

    if command == "a":
        add_to_cart(item, cart)
        print('added to cart')
    elif command == "d" and item in cart:
        delete_from_cart(item, cart)
    elif command == "q":
        return False
        print ('end process_order func')
    return True

def go_shopping():
    cart = dict()

while True:
    print ('start main loop')
    order = get_item()
    print ('exited process_order')
        if not process_order(order, cart):
            print ('if not')
            break
    print ('while loop end')
    print (cart)
    print ("Finished!")

go_shopping()
```

Comment: Why would it print "if not"???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because in the code there's a `print("if not")`.

Comment: @Rightleg Ah. I didn't see that. But it *does* print that, right?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Dunno lol. I'm not willing to run the whole code, since the question was focused on the time `process_order` method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, I am not really sure of your problem. But you seem concerned with the moment when `process_order` method is called.

When you write

```
if not process_order(order, cart)
```

it must be seen as follows (just adding parentheses):

```
if (not process_order(order, cart))
```

So you're asking Python to do something if the condition `not process_order(order, cart)` is true. So, Python must know the boolean value of the expression `not process_order(order, cart)`.

This expression is composed of a unary operator, `not`, and a non-elementary expression, `process_order(order, cart)`. That latter expression needs to be evaluated, so Python **has** to run the `process_order` method.

Therefore, when you write `if not process_order(order, cart)`, the `process_order` method is indeed executed.

Comment: Thank you.  The answers my question exactly.  I was not sure what the `if (not process_order(order, cart))` was applying logic to, but now I understand that it is applying it to the return value of `process_order`.  Thank you.